# Choose a random row as aggregate function in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I want to group by a column and then select random rows from another column. In Presto, there's `arbitrary`.

E.g. my query is:

```
SELECT a, arbitrary(b)
FROM foo
GROUP BY a
```

How do I do this in Hive?

**Edit:**

By "random", I meant "arbitrary". It could just be the first row every time.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I don't need a specific `b`, any one of them with each `a` is fine.

Comment: One point is if all `b` are the same. Another point is if many `b` have the same `a`, I don't care which `b` I get. E.g. `b` hashes to `a`.

Comment: Please add a data sample.

Comment: Speaking for the original poster, I think the idea would be to avoid the computational burden of determining the max or min, but use 'arbitrary' as part of a GROUP BY to avoid duplicates when they exist, but when the user doesn't care WHICH of the values is chosen. For example, maybe I want to aggregate by person and get one row per Social Security Number (unique), but I also want to get their first name in the result, but sometimes their first name is listed as 'Stephen' and sometimes 'Steven', but I don't care which one, and want my query to run faster by avoiding MAX/MIN.

Comment: `arbitrary` is okay to use in specific settings where its use can be made deterministic, or if it's unavoidably necessary in dealing with big data. It should not be used in default settings where it produces random output. Reproducibility is an important property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic to get your required result in Hive.
Provide a row_number to rand(b) and choose any row_number you want. Every time it will return a random value from column b.

```
select a, b
from (
select a, b,row_number() over( partition by a order by rand(b) asc) rn from foo
)a
where rn=1
group by a, b;
```